# Which STL container has facilities for slicing into two or more containers?

Tags: c++, stl

Say I have a vector / list whatever of ints populated with 2300 values
I want to be able to easily slice this into 4 vectors /lists (not necessarily of equal size). 
e.g.

```
vec1 ( elements 0 - 500 )
vec2 ( elements 501 - 999)
vec3 ( elements 1001 - 1499)
```

etc.

Comment: What do you want to do with the slices? There's probably a better way.

Comment: One use case is when I want to process each slice in a different thread. But I have no control over the size of the original list

Comment: Your threads should probably try to accept two iterators denoting the range then, if that's possible (aka, if the vector hangs around the entire duration the iterators are used).

Comment: That would be in line with the best scoring answer below. I am looking into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to do it would be to use the one container, and just define separate iterator ranges over it.

```
std::vector<int> vec(2300);

it0 = vec.begin();
it1 = vec.begin() + 500;
it2 = vec.begin() + 1000;
it3 = vec.begin() + 1500;
it4 = vec.begin() + 2000;
it5 = vec.end();
```

Now, the first range is simply defined by the iterators `it0` and `it1`. The second by `it1` and `it2`, and so on.

So, if you want to apply a function to every element in the third range, you'd simply do this:

```
std::for_each(it2, it3, somefunc);
```

Actually copying the elements into separate containers may be unnecessary, and would carry a performance cost.

Comment: FWIW, in C++11 code, `std::move_iterator` and `std::make_move_iterator` can be used to move the contents out of the original `vector` into new ones, eliminating copying and retaining the efficiency of this solution while properly separating everything into different containers.

Comment: @ildjarn: those are (of course) new to me; would there be a conceptual difference using those over, say, `vector<T> destination; destination.reserve(500); std::transform(vec.begin() + 500, vec.begin() + 1000, std::back_inserter(destination), somefunc);`?

Comment: @sehe : I'll just quote the FDIS. §24.5.3/1: "*Class template `move_iterator` is an iterator adaptor with the same behavior as the underlying iterator except that its dereference operator implicitly converts the value returned by the underlying iterator’s dereference operator to an rvalue reference. Some generic algorithms can be called with move iterators to replace copying with moving.*"

Comment: @sehe : The result is that `std::vector<T> vec1(make_move_iterator(vec.begin()), make_move_iterator(vec.begin() + 500));` would move the first 500 elements from `vec` to `vec1` rather than copying them.

Comment: Ah - so it's related to move constructors instead, really. Ok; I'll have that in the back of my head for a year or so

Comment: @ildjam: that would still be less efficient. It would replace each copy with a move, but a move is still more expensive than a no-op.

Comment: The problem here would be that you lose information on how big is each iterator/vector.

Comment: @Diego: not at all. The size of the third range is `it3 - it2`, a constant-time operation.

Comment: @jalf: Yes, of course, but you have to keep in mind for every algorithm/loop/whatever, afterwards, that you have to keep those two iterators together. I think using `boost::range`, for example, is a better option.

Comment: @Diego: then you have to include a third-party library, just so you can call `begin()` and `end()` on it to get the iterators you started with back. Perhaps. It's a valid option, and I agree, in some cases it is very worthwhile. But it is little more than syntactic sugar on top of the iterator-based solution.

Answer (score 4):

`std::list` would be the best choice, as you just build lists by joining pointers. Finding the exact place to slice would be the problem, though, because you have to *reach* that point in the list iterator to make the cut.

**EDIT**:

As per comments (thanks for the insights), maybe using `std::vector<int>` and iterators is a good idea. However, with plain iterators, you loose the length of the vector, so I propose using, for instance, a `boost::range_iterator`:

```
std::vector<int> vec(2300);

it0 = vec.begin();
it1 = vec.begin() + 500;
it2 = vec.begin() + 1000;
it3 = vec.begin() + 1500;
it4 = vec.begin() + 2000;
it5 = vec.end;

typedef boost::iterator_range< std::vector<int>::iterator > my_slice_t;

my_slice_t slice1 = boost::make_iterator_range(it0, it1);
...
```

Then, you can use slice1 as a normal, underlying `std::vector<int>` as per iteration:

```
std::for_each(slice1.begin(), slice1.end(), /* stuff */);
```

Comment: For 2,300 `int` objects, I'd be very surprised if splicing new lists from a `std::list<int>` performed better than having a `std::vector<int>` and copying the elements into new vectors.  Sure, with a list the splice is fast, but you have the overhead of allocating 2,300 nodes and as you point out, the lack of random access iteration makes finding the delimiting nodes expensive.

Comment: It also depends in how he or she *obtains* data. If he or she can be storing the list iterators on the go, the performance won't hurt.

Comment: @Diego: in that case, the exact same goes for building separate vectors in the first place, making list once again more expensive. Now, the trouble is, most likely, the size of the input cannot always be known up front. This is one case where a linked list _might_ become more efficient. Especially when storing some 'grid' of iterators in an index for quick access.

Comment: @Diego: Would you care to generalize this to a case where the size of the original vector is not known at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

See the fourth `std::vector<>` constructor documented [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/vector/constructor).

```
// given std::vector<T> vec with 2300 elements
std::vector<T> vec1(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 500);
std::vector<T> vec2(vec.begin() + 500, vec.begin() + 1000);
std::vector<T> vec3(vec.begin() + 1000, vec.begin() + 1500);
std::vector<T> vec4(vec.begin() + 1500, vec.begin() + 2000);
std::vector<T> vec5(vec.begin() + 2000, vec.end());
```

Comment: I can only say it again and again: Iterators are a damn powerful concept. +1

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is doable with the vector container

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
  vector<int> ints ;
  vector<int> ints_sliced;

  int i ;

  // populate
  for( i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) 
    ints.push_back(i) ;

  // slice from 10-19
  ints_sliced.insert(ints_sliced.begin(), ints.begin()+10, ints.begin()+20) ;

  // inspect
  vector<int>::iterator it ;
  for( it = ints_sliced.begin() ; it != ints_sliced.end() ; it++ )
    cout << *it << endl ;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jalf's correct observation that actually copying the subvectors into fresh vectors might be a waste of time and space, let me point at [valarray](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/).

### Intro: valarray

Valarray may be more complicated, but especially in the face of parallel processing, might lead to better ways to subvector work for the different threads.  Things to look for:

1. algorithmic pre-science (if locations in a certain pattern have a certain property (e.g. are known to be zero), you can hand it to an optimized worker for those values)
2. subvector alignment (the aligment can make or break the availability of SIMD, SSE4 optimized versions; have a look at gcc -ftree-vectorizer for more background)

Now valarrays have quite a number of 'obscure' operations and tricks to them (gslices; basically revectored array dimensions to address the original array) that I won't go into here, but suffice it to say, if you want to do number crunching across subsets of contiguous arrays of (mainly) floating points[1], it will pay to read up on those.

### Mandatory (braindead) teaser

```
// mask_array example
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  valarray<int> myarray (10);
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) myarray[i]=i;   //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

  valarray<bool> mymask (10);
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    mymask[i]= ((i%2)==1);                 //  f  t  f  t  f  t  f  t  f  t

  myarray[mymask] *= valarray<int>(10,5);  //  0 10  2 30  4 50  6 70  8 90
  myarray[!mymask] = 0;                    //  0 10  0 30  0 50  0 70  0 90

  cout << "myarray:\n";
  for (size_t i=0; i<myarray.size(); ++i)
      cout << myarray[i] << ' ';
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This was copied verbatim from the above link, you will want to adapt to your specific need. There was probably a good reason why you kept the endgoal a bit vague, so I'll happily leave the rest of the work to you!

### Wrapup

If you really want to go all the way, however, you should start looking at the big guns (Blitz++, et al.).

[1] these have historically been the focus for vectorized CPU instruction sets. However, als @jalf notes, SSE2 and higher includes SIMD integer instructions as well

Comment: Regarding your footnote, x86 CPUs have a full set of integer SIMD operations as of SSE2

Comment: This is the closest to built-in slicing but I was looking for a general puprose container not just for numeric values. My end goal is to be able to process each slice of the container in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, if you happen to be using g++ and GNU stdlibc++, you can use roughly

```
g++ -march=native -O3 -ftree-vectorize ...
```

If you also throw in GNU OpenMP support (libgomp) you can benefit (*evaluate, profile*!) from automatic parallelization of standard algorithms,

```
g++ -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL -fopenmp -march=native -O3 .... -lgomp
```

YMMV - I wanted to just throw this out there, because e.g. the parallel for_each seems to be close to what you want (but, automagic and self-adapting to container size, iterator type and number of processors)

Comment: @user754425 this would apply to general purpose containers a.o.t. the valarray suggestion